# Fiddler - cannot decrypt SSL Traffic - unspecified CryptographicException

Tags: ssl, encryption, fiddler

I am having problems decrypting any SSL traffic (my Windows 10 PC) using (thelatest version of) Fiddler.

I have tried Eric's (created Fiddler) post on resetting certificates to no avail:
http://textslashplain.com/2015/10/30/reset-fiddlers-https-certificates/

I am seeing the following error in the logs on all SSL requests:

**`09:50:02:3744 fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to www.fiddler2.com (for #1) failed. System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException Unspecified error`**

To try and isolate the issue I installed Charles and it is able to decrpyt SSL requests so I dont believe it is a system-wide / local network issue.

Any help much appreciated as Fiddler is such an excellent tool.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as it isn't about programming itself. However, when asking questions at any SE site: please remember we cannot debug on your computer. Your question doesn't contain enough info to solve the issue, it seems to me.

Comment: I appreciate you cant debug my machine, I was hoping someone else might have faced the same issue and could offer some insight.

Answer (score 0):

So I have now got Fiddler working again, these steps fixed my problem:

- Remove Fiddler certificates (via the GUI, and manually check in Certificates mmc)
- Uninstall Fiddler, including all settings data
- Use a registry cleaner to clean up orphan / broken entries
- Delete any remnant folder related to Fiddler
- Download latest version of Fiddler
- Install using all defaults (dont install to a custom location)
- Set HTTPS Capture and Decrypt in Fiddler

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue on mac with Fiddler. This was the first time I was using fiddler with mac.

> The problem was the mac was not trusting the Fiddler
> certificate.

To solve it I first of all, go to the Fiddler and then choose

1. Tools>Options>HTTPS
2. check *Decrypt HTTPS Traffic*
3. In the same dialog, then go to actions and click on export root certificate to the Desktop
4. click ok and close the fiddler.

Now the fiddler certificate has been downloaded on your desktop. In my case its name was FiddlerRoot.cer .
Double click on it and it will open in the keychain.

1. Select certificate option from left hand under category
2. You will find there is a certificate with name DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot
3. Right click on the certificate and click on the Trust to make it expand. Here is how my dialog looks now.
   [image]
4. In your case instead of Always trust, use system defaults would have been selected by default. Select Always trust.
5. Clear cookies and cache of your browser and then restart the browser.

Now if I start my fiddler it is able to decrypt the https website.